# EF Core and SQL multiple cascade

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to model payments in ef-core using SQL Server. A payment has a from side and a to side, in this case say a user or actor for each.  I have a transaction class that has relationships to a FromActor and to a ToActor.  The generated migration fails to update in the database, saying there may be multiple cascade paths.  I have read that I need to override the default cascades in OnModelCreating method in the db context but I am not sure how.  Fairly new to EF and migrations, I am just following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio.

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Transaction> Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
  
    public int FromActorId { get; set; }
    public Actor FromActor { get; set; }
    public int ToActorId { get; set; }
    public Actor ToActor { get; set; }
}
```

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Transactions_Actors_ToActorId' on table 'Transactions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Can you please let me know how to make this work in the db context?  Or do I need to model my domain differently?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ??
    }
```

Update: based on all the comments I received here is the final working solution for me -

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Transaction> FromTransactions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Transaction> ToTransactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    
    public int FromActorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; }
    public int ToActorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor ToActor { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(t => t.FromActor)
                .WithMany(a => a.FromTransactions)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.FromActorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Transaction_Id_From_Actor");
            entity.HasOne(t => t.ToActor)
                .WithMany(a => a.ToTransactions)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.ToActorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Transaction_Id_To_Actor");
        });

        Seed(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void Seed(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("Data/Actors.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var actors = csv.GetRecords<Actor>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor>().HasData(actors.ToArray());
        }
    }

protected async Task<Transaction> SaveTransactionAsync()
    {
        using (var context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var transaction = new Transaction()
            {
              TimestampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
              Amount = 20.45,   // hardcoded for illustration
              FromActorId = 1,  // hardcoded for illustration. Using id from actor seed file.
              ToActorId = 2,    // hardcoded for illustration. Using id from actor seed file.
            };
            context.Add(transaction);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            await context.Entry(transaction).Reference(t => t.FromActor).LoadAsync();
            await context.Entry(transaction).Reference(t => t.ToActor).LoadAsync();
            logger.LogDebug("Saved transaction to database.");
            return transaction;
        }
        
    }
```

The main lessons besides disabling delete cascade were I HAD to introduce 2 collections for the Actor (from and to).  And also I could not set the FromActor and ToActor properties of the Transaction during save; only set the ids.  Setting the objects would try to insert into Actors table during a transaction save.  Not intuitive.

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the properties of your modelbuilder for each of your entities the way you want to with the modelBuilder yes :

if I were to give you an example with your actors, it could be :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(t => t.FromActor)
                    .WithMany(a => a.TransactionsFrom)
                    .HasForeignKey(t => t.FromActorId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                    .HasConstraintName("fk_transaction_from_id_from_actor");
                entity.HasOne(t => t.ToActor)
                    .WithMany(a => a.TransactionsTo)
                    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ToActorId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                    .HasConstraintName("fk_transaction_to_id_to_actor");
            });
    }
```

Or something similar. As you can see, the syntax is pretty self-explanatory.

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    #region InverseProperty
    public ICollection<Transaction> TransactionsFrom {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Transaction> TransactionsTo {get; set; }
    #endregion InverseProperty
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
  
    public int FromActorId { get; set; }
    public int ToActorId { get; set; }

    #region ForeignKey
    public virtual Actor ToActor { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; }
    #endregion ForeignKey
}
```

The entity Transaction has one Actor FromActor, that FromActor has a list of Transactions (TransactionsFrom). The foreign key should be FromActorId, and on delete, you don't do anything to the entity. The name of the contraint should be "fk_transaction_id_from_actor".

This allows you to change constraints, behaviours and naming at will. It can also permit you to add data in the model if necessary through migration :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Actor>().HasData(
                new
                {
                    ActorId = 1,
                    FirstName = "John",
                    LastName = "Doe"
                },
                new
                {
                    ActorId = 2,
                    FirstName = "Jane",
                    LastName = "Doe"
                });
```

Every change in the context will be registered in the next migration when you do your "dotnet ef migrations add myMigration", so if you add data in the HasData, and you don't work alone on the project, be sure to keep track of the ids or the migration will fail !
I hope that was enough to help you.

Comment: Getting this error now: Cannot create a relationship between 'Actor.Transactions' and 'Transaction.ToActor' because a relationship already exists between 'Actor.Transactions' and 'Transaction.FromActor'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Transaction.ToActor' first in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: That's because your "Transactions" property on Actors is currently an aggregation of what EF Core considers "Two different things" meaning transactions where an actor is the beneficiary or the issuer. I've never seen such an aggregate like that so infortunately I can't answer your question. One way to solve this would be to have two "TransactionsFrom" and "TransactionTo" but that may not be what you want/need conceptually. Serge seemed to have catched on this problem before me =)

Comment: Ok I will update my Actor model to have FromTransactions and ToTransactions.  Seems EF still has a way to go to be useful in real world as an ORM without requiring the user to adapt to it vs the other way around.

Comment: Update: so after adding From and To transactions to the Actor model, I am able to update the database. I even seed the Actors in the OnModelCreating, no problem.  However when i simply make a new Transaction object with 2 existing actors in the database, save changes is attempting to INSERT INTO ACTORS ?? which fails obviously. Sounds like I am still stuck.  Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Actors' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Update2: I changed my new Transcation() to only add the FromActorId and ToActorId and omitted the actual FromActor and ToActor objects.  That seems to have done the trick and now I can save transactions.  In conjunction I made FromActor and ToActor virtual properties.

Comment: thank you, I'll edit my answer to reflect that, as people don't always read comments

Comment: Well that results in a final remark that's incomprehensible at best but probably not true at all. The truth is that `Actor.Transactions` (you also forgot the 's') can't be the inverse property of two properties in `Transaction`. See Serge's answer, which is right in this part but, unfortunately, not 100% correct because it requires explicit mapping code to connect the ends of the relationships in both classes. Properties being virtual or not has nothing to do with this.

Comment: After your revision: that at least removed this confusing part, but the fact remains, you can't use `WithMany(a => a.Transactions)` twice with different inverse properties.

Comment: Well I thought that too, but apparently Heems managed to according to their updates above ? I mean I may have misunderstood obviously, I have not reproduced the code. And as I've said earlier, I have never tried to mash two different collections into one before. I would have made all foreign inverse properties virtual and would have added two ICollection<Transaction> into Actor, just like Serge posted, but I seem to gather from Heems' post that they still have one Transactions ?

Comment: I have no idea what Heems did, non of the comments gives a complete picture. As for your own answer, it would really help to test code before testing. I wish everybody did.

Comment: sorry. I only wanted to help a bit, but it's pretty obvious I'm not made for that. If you want to post an accurate answer, I'll remove mine. I'm not making the mistake of posting here anymore anyway

Comment: Please do go on posting answers. I started posting answers years ago to force myself to learn all this EF stuff. It's not hard to test the code, is it? You were on the right track with the two collections.

Comment: Updated post with my final working solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add some navigation properties to your classes

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
     .....

    public virtual List<Transaction> FromActors {get; set;} 
   public virtual List<Transaction> ToActors { get; set; }

}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    ....

    public int? FromActorId { get; set; }
    public  virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; }

    public int? ToActorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor ToActor { get; set; }
}
```